# I'm using some code I found online to run a raspberry pi temperature sensor and I'm not the best coder

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, temperature

I'm using some code I found online to run a raspberry pi temperature sensor and I'm not the best coder so I need your help!

This is the code by the way

---

```
import os
import glob
import time

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_c, temp_f

while True:
    print(read_temp())  
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

Im trying to do two things

a) Make so the temperature is updated very frequently

b) Make so the temperatures it gives me are not ludicrously long (45.9992919193994949393)
(My dad, the coder, is on a business call so he couldn't help me out this time but he mentioned something about floaters or something but I have no clue what that means)

So if someone could maybe explain how to do those two things that would be spectacular. Or, if you want to be a god, note out (or whatever you call it when you //BlahBlah in code) the entire code explaining what each line does as well as answer my two questions. Thank you for anyone who tries to help I really do appreciate it.

**Bonus:**I Think I will probably end up attempting to graph the data eventually so if someone knows of how to do that and could explain it I would be VERY happy.

Comment: You might get a better answer over @ http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
time.sleep(0.2)
```

You have the refresh rate (0.2s) of reading temp. Change it if you like it.

In this line:

```
print(read_temp())
```

You output the temperature. Rewrite it this way:

```
print("%.2f" % read_temp())
```

Then, change the number after the . to change the numbers of decimals (in my example, you would have 2 decimal points).

And, finally, changing:

```
time.sleep(1)
```

You change the display refresh rate.
Guess that`s it.